# How Do I Combine Two Query Results In To A Map, In Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

I'm new to Grails development.

I have a domain class like this :

```
class DaySchedule {
    Date Todaysdate
    String startTime;
    String endTime;
    String task
    int priority 
    boolean completed
    static belongsTo = [ schedule : Schedule ]
}
```

I have bootstrapped with some test data's. Now I want to do a query, with following condition :

- I need to pick each `task` (which are stored in `bootstrap.groovy`) which are belongs to a particular`Todaysdate`.

For example if I have these statements in my `BootStrap.groovy` :

```
//other codes
def daySchedule3 = new DaySchedule(Todaysdate:new Date(),
                startTime:"6pm",endTime:"10pm",
                task:"ReaD git...",completed:false)
def daySchedule4 = new DaySchedule(Todaysdate:new Date()+1,
                startTime:"10am",endTime:"12pm",
                task:"Read MySQL....",completed:false)
```

Now clearly the `task`, `ReaD git...` belongs to a day (which is today as I have passed `new Date()` into it).

To find these I came up with a partial solution like this:

```
        def allTasks = DaySchedule.findAllByTaskIsNotNull()
        def dates  = allTasks.collect { it.Todaysdate }
        def tasks = dates.collect { 
                    def queryParameter = new DaySchedule(Todaysdate:it)
                    def todaysWork = DaySchedule.findAll(queryParameter)
                    todaysWork.task 
        }
```

I have a problem with this code. I couldn't use `collectEntries` method on the `dates` and `tasks` so that I convert it into map of a particular date(i.e `dates`) with values as `tasks`. (which is what I tried for!)

Now I'm left lone. I couldn't not able to find a way to guess for which `dates` the `tasks` belongs to.

Any other solutions for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get a map with a key of the date, and a value of the task name, for all of the domain objects `DaySchedule`.  You may want to try [`Collection.groupBy`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#groupBy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).  For example:

```
def allTasks = DaySchedule.findAllByTaskIsNotNull()

def tasksByDate = [:] // start with empty map

tasksByDate.putAll(
    allTasks.groupBy { task ->
        // group by just the date portion, ignoring time
        // clone since clearTime modifies original
        task.todaysDate.clone().clearTime()
    }.collect { date, daySchedule ->
        // change from map of date -> daySchedule to map of date -> task
        [date, daySchedule.task] as MapEntry
    }
)
```

Comment: the `groupBy` method is returning the `null` as the key value. Not the `todaysDate`...

Comment: Are the dates coming back null from `findAllByTaskIsNotNull`?  Also, make sure you get the capitalization right; you've got `Todaysdate` in your code, but I used the more conventional `todaysDate`.

Comment: ya I have changed `Todaysdate` properly. And from `findAllByTaskIsNotNull` all dates are coming back properly. I guess the problem is with `clone().clearTime()` this line of code...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a design problem somewhere... it would be easier to have something like :

```
class Task {
    Date startTime;  
    Date endTime;
    String description
    int priority 
    boolean completed
    static belongsTo = [ schedule : Schedule ]

    String toString() {
        return "${description} : from ${startTime} to ${endTime}"
    }

}
```

Then, you can list all the dates for which you have tasks in them like this :

```
java.text.DateFormat df = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.US);

def days = Task.list().collect {
      df.format(it.startTime);
}.unique()
```

So now the "days" variable contains an array of strings of unique days present in your database with tasks associated.

If you want to list the tasks by day, you can then do :

```
days.each { dayString ->
    def date = df.parse(dayString)
    def dayTasks = Task.findAllByStartTimeBetween(date, date+1)
    println "Tasks for ${dayString}"
    dayTasks.each {
        println "    - ${it}"
    }
}
```

Comment: what your saying your is right. My main aim is to render all the tasks on a each day. Now the problem becomes, how I will use `findAllByStartTimeBetween(date1, date2)` for all possible `todaysDate` from my table? Thats why I didn't use them.....

Comment: Can you use grails 2.0 ? That will be easier with the new where queries syntax and usage of the date functions I guess : see http://www.grails.org/doc/2.0.0/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries and scroll down to the "Other functions" chapter...

Comment: Yup will migrate soon.... And I guess as @ataylor have told, the `groupBy` method does the job (in my case) quite well and its easy to maintain.. Any how thanks for your answer...